# How to get all matches in Python using RegEx when the pattern has similar text?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the following sample string:

> this is a test of the loss of offsite power

I have the following tags:

> offsite power, loss of offsite power

I'm attempting to get all matches from the string. However when I have this code:

```
import re

description = 'this is a test of the loss of offsite power'
all_tags = ['offsite power', 'loss of offsite power']
reg_ex = '|'.join(['\\b%s\\b' % t for t in all_tags])

expression = re.compile(reg_ex, re.IGNORECASE)

matches = re.findall(expression, description)

results = [m for m in matches]

print results
```

My results are as follows:

```
['loss of offsite power']
```

I need to get both instances of the tags. I know I can do this by looping through each tag and then searching the description on each tag, but is there a way to do this in 1 search?

My code is for Python 2.7, however I will accept Python 3 answers as well.

Note: my list of final keywords is approximately 2000 phrases similar to the above.

Comment: Are the tags *literals*?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes they are. It has to be exact match for each of the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple: use the newer [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module by *Matthew Barnett* which allows overlapping matches. In `Python`:

```
import regex as re
string = 'this is a test of the loss of offsite power'

all_tags = ['offsite power', 'loss of offsite power']
reg_ex = '|'.join(['\\b%s\\b' % t for t in all_tags])

expression = re.compile(reg_ex, re.IGNORECASE)

# mind overlapped=True !
matches = re.findall(expression, string, overlapped=True)
print matches
# ['loss of offsite power', 'offsite power']
```

To get the module, simply do `pip install regex` on the command line. It works with `re.finditer()` as well.

Comment: @JasonHeine: Glad to help :)